# More than one result in a field

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

If I have a table "messages" and users can send the same message to more than one user, when I show the messages how can I group all the users in a field?

```
ID  SUBJECT MESSAGE    FROM     TO
 1  Test 1  Message       1     John    
 2  Test 2  Message       2     Jackson
```

THIS IS MY SELECT:

```
SELECT messages.id_message, subject, body_message, name_user, 
from messages, registro_mensajes
INNER JOIN users on messages.id_user_sender = users.id_user
```

DATABASE:

MESSAGES

```
id_message
subject
body_message
id_user_sender
```

REGIST

```
id_regist
id_message
id_user_sender
id_user_destin
```

Thx

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Because if not then your question runs the risk of being unintelligible, and then no one will answer it.

Comment: Use a group by and GROUP_CONCAT on the user column. That column will then be a comma separated list of users.

Comment: @SloanThrasher 's comment is going to annoy @Strawberry. It's often better to do this kind of aggregation in client software (php?) than with the MySQL-only `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Comment: The OPs question seems pretty straight forward to me, "how to get multiple values in one field", hence the suggestion. While the question content could be more complete, it seems like a simple question, so I gave a simple answer.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn´t clear enoght. I know how to do it with PHP but I was told to do it with a select. THX for the help.

Comment: Man, it's like OJ's inside my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT()` is the excellent, though MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)-specific, [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) for handling this requirement.

You can try something like this.

```
 SELECT a.message_id, a.message_text, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.user ORDER BY b.user) users
   FROM message a
   LEFT JOIN destination b ON a.message_id = b.message_id
  GROUP BY a.message_id, a.message_text
```

(Sorry, I cannot figure out your table structure from your question, so this is an example).

The trouble with `GROUP_CONCAT()`, and the reason some developers avoid it, is this: it converts perfectly good normalized data into a denormalized resultset.  Comma-separated values in columns are a real hassle. But if you only use it for display, it should be fine.

Comment: 10/10  Worked perfectly. THX